# Sorting behavior on passing function vs. passing anonymous closure

Tags: javascript, sorting, scope, closures

## Problem and Question

I have a small application that asynchronously gets JSON data from a server, formats it into a table, and allows the user to perform some simple operations on the table (sorting, filtering, etc.).

One of the sorting functions accesses DOM elements in the previously-generated table (definition given below).

```
    var SORT = function(){
             var my = {};
             // public methods
             my.byName = function(sign){    
                     (!sign) ? sign=1 : 1;
                     var T = $("#resultArea").find("tbody");
                     var R = T.children("tr");
                     R.sort( function(a,b){
                             var an = $(a).attr("data-name");
                             var bn = $(b).attr("data-name");
                             return sign * an.localeCompare(bn);
                             });
                     R.detach().appendTo(T);
                    }
...
return my; }();
```

When specifying it as a callback for an element the user can click on, I have two formulations.

`$("#sort-button").click(SORT.byName);` (pass function as argument)

OR

`$("sort-button").click(function(){SORT.byName();});` (pass anonymous closure that calls the function)

The first option fails, but the second works. Here is how it fails on a test case with 536 rows to be sorted:

- Former row 2 (which precedes row 1 in alphabetical order) is moved to position 268.
- Former row 269 is moved to position 536.
- Former row 536 is moved to position 2.

I have tried and failed to construct a MWE that fails in the same way (will update question once I succeed). Questions are: What went wrong? Why does using the anonymous closure work?

## Update

An earlier version of the snippet had been sanitized to remove the parameter `sign` and the line at the start (which would set sign to 1 if it evaluated to false or was undefined), the idea being that by passing `sign=-1` as a parameter, a descending sort could be done. When I removed `sign` from the definition in the live code, the problem went away.

So I found that the offending line is `(!sign) ? sign=1 : 1;` When replaced by the more transparent `if(sign !== undefined){sign=1;}` the problem goes away. I think what it does is that it sets **global** `sign` to  one on the first pass, then on the second pass, sign is defined so it **returns** `1`, and the function ends (only one pass having been completed).

Then why does this error not crash the sort on the anonymous closure approach?

Comment: Given that `byName` does not use `this` anywhere nor does take any arguments, there should not be any observable difference.

Comment: That `SORT` object is created before you attach the click handler, and never altered after that, right?

Comment: @Bergi correct. SORT is defined once with some methods to be called on certain user events. Still can't reproduce the bug. the same failure mode occurs both with numeric and alpha sorts.

Comment: @Bergi actually your first comment made me realize that I had omitted one detail in cleaning up the code to post... I had removed a parameter that I thought was unrelated. Will update question now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you found out, the problem comes from that `sign` parameter. When you pass a function as the event handler and call `SORT.byName()` without arguments, you'll get `sign=1` and everything is as expected. But when you pass the function directly as the handler, it will get called *with the `Event` object* as its argument. Suddenly you have an object in your `sign` variable, and multiplying that with a number will yield `NaN` (an invalid result for a comparison function), which completely messes up your sort.

> When replaced by the more transparent `if(sign !== undefined){sign=1;}` the problem goes away. I think what it does is that it sets global sign to one on the first pass…

Nope. There is no global `sign` variable at all. And I guess you actually wanted `if (sign === undefined) sign = 1;`. Which wouldn't work as well when passing in events, so you might want to use `if (!Number.isFinite(sign)) sign = 1;`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. This also explains why I have access to the event object (when normally I don't get to pass variables when passing a callback function as argument directly).

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing more of your code I can't really tell what's going on. The snippet you have posted seems alright. Regarding your question, there is a subtle difference when you pass `SORT.byName` vs. sending it wrapped in an anonymous function. Specifically, it is the value of `this` in the `byName` function when it is executed.

When you do `click(SORT.byName)`, you are sending a direct reference to the function, which means that when it gets called, the value of `this` is whatever the jQuery handler for `click` sets it to be when before it calls your callback function; usually this is a reference to the element that fired the event.

However, when you do `click(function() { SORT.byName(); })`, the value of `this` in `byName` is the `SORT` object (but `this` in the anonymous function is still whatever jQuery sets it to). This is because here you're invoking the function explicitly as a *method* of the `SORT` object.

So if your sort functions rely on the value of `this` and assume it to be the `SORT` object, you can run into issues.

Here's some code that demonstrates this behavior:

```
var obj = {
    field: 10,
    method: function() {
        console.log(this);
    }
};

// The first argument to apply sets the value of "this"
function call(f) {
    f.apply("not this", []);
}

call(obj.method); //logs "not this"
call(function() { // logs obj
    obj.method();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Searching through the DOM and sorting is not fun.  You would be better off keeping some state, sorting, and then appending the new results to the DOM after you remove the old like so.

```
var myNumbers = [
    [1,'one'],
    [4,'four'],
    [2,'two'],
    [6,'six'],
    [3,'three'],
    [8,'eight'],
    [7,'seven'],
    [5,'five'],
    [10,'ten'],
    [9,'nine']
];

myNumbers.sort(function(a,b){
    if (a[0] > b[0]) {
        return 1;
    }
    if (a[0] > b[0]) {
        return -1;
    }
  return 0;
});

var T = $("tbody");
var R = T.children("tr");

R.detach()
```

After that you can prepend your results in a loop like you addElemnt function but a loop instead.